# Solution to the "cubic" Helmholtz equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

What is known about the solutions of the differential equation in three-dimensions

$$
\nabla^2 \phi = -\kappa^2 (\phi  + (1/3!)\phi^3)
$$

Without the cubic term, this gives a linear operator $\mathcal{L} = \nabla^2 + \kappa^2$. In this case I can get a solution via the Green's function $G=\exp{(i\kappa r)}(4\pi r)^{-1}$. In my equation however, the presence of $\phi^3$ does not give me a linear operator. Is anything known about the solution to this equation?

**Context**: The [Poisson-Boltzmann equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Boltzmann_equation) can be put into the functional form of $\nabla^2 \phi = -\kappa^2 \sinh \phi$. Expanding sinh to first order gives the [Helmholtz equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) as mentioned above. The second order term is zero and the third order term gives the equation in question.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105119/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00033-020-01367-9) paper discusses your problem below Eq. 8 and provides the solution in Eq. 9 and 10 for a single plate and Eq. 11 and 12 for two plates.